# Use iOS 6 simulator in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I've downloaded in Xcode 5 component iOS 6 simulator. I'm able to test my application on iOS 7 simulator without any problems. Now I want to check my application on iOS 6 simulator. How should I force to launch my application on specify simulator version?

When I switch my simulator:

```
Hardware -> Device -> iPhone Retina -> iOS 6
```

Then I see correct version, but when I launch my application then version of simulator switch again to iOS 7.

Do you have any advices how can avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your deployment target to support iOS 6. As follows:

- Select your application target in Xcode
- Open the Build Settings tab for the target
- Set the deployment target to iOS6.0

[image: set deployment target]

. . having done this, you will now see both iOS6(.1) and iOS7 listed as simulator targets:

[image: targets]

Comment: Thanks Jasper for the hint. It works for me, when I set iOS Deployment Target to iOS 6.0 (not 6.1).

Comment: @Grzegorz Oops, excuse the typing mistake. Fixed. (Pics stay the same, as I only have the two sims currently installed).